# Sum of multiplication of columns for rows with similar IDs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I have 3 columns in a table called "purchases":

```
id         amount         price
2          2              21
2          5              9
3          8              5
```

I want to group all rows with similar IDs and have this array as a result:

```
array([0] => [id => 2, total => 87 (because 2*21+5*9=87)], [1] => [id => 3, total => 40 (because 8*5=40)])
```

as **total accounts for SUM(amount*price) for rows with similar IDs**.

I've tried using

```
SELECT id, SUM(p.price*p.amount) total FROM purchases p GROUP by p.id
```

but it doesn't work well (i.e. it doesn't achieve what I want, which is what I wrote above).
Any ideas on how to do this in mysql?

An example of what the query returns:

```
    id         amount         price
    2          3              89
    2          3              19

    SELECT id, SUM(p.price*p.amount) total FROM purchases p GROUP by p.id

==> [id => 2, total => 183]
```

Comment: What is it actually doing? What do you want it to do? They are the two vital things _every_ question should have. The phrase "it doesn't work well" is _not_ a good problem report.

Comment: I've given an example, read the example.

Comment: What *does* it return? What are your exact data?

Comment: are you sure you're executing two queries on the same database?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT
id, 
SUM(amount*price) AS total
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

Data:

```
| id | amount | price |
|----|--------|-------|
| 2  | 3      | 19    |
| 2  | 3      | 89    |
| 3  | 203    | 1     |
```

Result:

```
id  total
2   324
3   203
```

Comment: That's exactly what I said wasn't working for me. Copy & paste still hasn't solved it.

Comment: this is no different from the query he wrote. How would this help him ?

Comment: Well it works on my MySQL test server at least and gives exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

@sombe: I've just tested your query and it works just fine. Are you sure your mysql is up to date?

[image]

The second works fine too:

[image]

Comment: Yes (5). I thought the query was fine too, but for instance for 3*89+3*19 it returns 183 (I have no idea how it got there).

Comment: I just tried with the data that should give an error but it works fine here. You should try to update your mysql since more likely you are running a really old version.